# How to change appstore application icon

Tags: iphone, ios, sdk

Hi can any one suggest me it is possible or not and if possible then how?

The premise is that the user pays for the app via a website and they gets an access code to send to her guests via the website.  The user downloads the free app from the iPhone store and enters the code.  We're trying to figure out if we can enable each user to customize the app icon so it can appear with a different image or text on the user phone.

Comment: The answers and comments have become confusing because you're rolling two very different questions into one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. The application's icon (and the application's property list file) is in the application bundle, which cannot be modified.

This would also violate the iOS SDK Terms of Use and the iTunes Store Terms of Service; you cannot have a third-party receive payment to access a free iOS application.

Comment: There are services that do this on the App Store though. Do you think it goes down to if Apple know if it is a paid-for service or not?

Comment: I am not aware of any apps that do this. Can you provide an example?

Comment: I wrote a front end app for a client who provides a service which isn't free. The user has a login and without that the app does nothing. Off the top of my head, I can only think of Spotify.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the iOS icon of a web app clipping, and put the web site to be clipped behind your private paywall.  Apple has been reported in the past to accept App store apps that generate URLs to customized clippable web apps.  No idea if they currently or will continue to do so.

Icons on App store iOS apps for stock OS devices can only be changed by Apple approving an update.

Answer (score 0):

Evan is right... This goes against so many terms of the iOS SDK.

One thing you could do (but I can't guarantee it will be accepted by Apple) is create a registration system on your website. Then have a login on the App as soon as it loads and check that the user has a valid account which has paid the subscription. You would have to handle all of your payment stuff on the webside though, meaning the app would be useless unless the user has already sorted that out. *If you do this, on submission of your app make sure you provide Apple with a demo account username and password!*

As for the icon, you can't change it once the App is submitted. It is bundled in with your app binary and there is also a logo included in iTunes connect. You can change them, but only by submitting a new binary.